# RealUrl - language path segment

Tags: typo3, realurl

My realurl.conf contains the following:

```
'2' => array (
    'GETvar' => 'L',
        'valueMap' => array (
        'en' => '1',
        'nl' => '2',
        'be-nl' => '3
        'be-fr' => '4'
    ),
    'noMatch' => 'bypass',
),
```

and:

```
array(
    'GETvar' => 'L',
    'value' => '3',
    'urlPrepend' => 'http://www.example.be',
    'useConfiguration' => 'www.example.be',
),

array(
    'GETvar' => 'L',
    'value' => '4',
    'urlPrepend' => 'http://www.example.be/fr',
    'useConfiguration' => 'www.example.be/fr',
),
```

and:

```
[globalVar= GP:L=4]
  //french (Belgium) = 4
  config{
    sys_language_uid = 4
    language = fr
    htmlTag_setParams = lang="fr"
    locale_all = fr_FR.UTF-8
    sys_language_mode = content_fallback;4,8
  }
  page.bodyTagCObject.30.value = fr
[global]
```

In T3 backend the url "www.example.be/fr" is configured properly and content is there for the specific languages.

When I go to www.example.be/fr, I get the L-parameter 3 and the content for the language id 3. Could anyone help me out on this?

Comment: I assume you get problems if you add a pathsegment to the domain. `www.example.be/fr` is no proper domain and I consider it a bug if you can declare a domain with a `/` inside. at least realurl seems to consider only the pure domain part.

Comment: You miss a comma and an apostroph in your first code snipped after `'be-nl' => '3`